# How can I properly generate URL parameters from nested JSON parameters in Python requests

Tags: python, rest, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests to pass a number of conditions to the Connectwise REST api. I'm trying to generate a URL like below

```
/company/configurations/?pageSize=1000&conditions=id=83500 and type/name="Printer" and name="TEST API PRINTER"
```

but I only seem to be able to generate this:

```
/company/configurations/?pageSize=1000&conditions=id&conditions=type/name&conditions=name
```

My payload looks like this:

```
parameters = {}
    parameters['conditions'] = {}
    parameters['pageSize'] = 1000
    if db_rid:
        parameters['conditions']['id'] = 83500
    if type_name:
        parameters['conditions']['type/name'] = "Printer"
    if name:
        parameters['conditions']['name'] = "TEST API PRINTER"
requests.get(APIurl, params=parameters)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That's because the value of "conditions" in the original url is one long string, `id=83500 and type/name="Printer" and name="TEST API PRINTER"`.  It's not some sort of magic nested parameters.  You just need to set the `conditions` parameter equal to that string.

Comment: use string `parameters['conditions'] = 'id=83500 and ...'`

Comment: I thought that may be the case, I've opted for building a function to build the string for me which I'll put in the answers below.
Thanks for the clarity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a function to generate the conditions string for this.

```
    def _add_condition(self, string, add_string, add_value):
    if string == '':
        if type(add_value) is not str:
            result = '{}={}'.format(add_string, add_value)
        else:
            result = '{}="{}"'.format(add_string, add_value)
    else:
        if type(add_value) is not str:
            result = '{} and {}={}'.format(string, add_string, add_value)
        else:
            result = '{} and {}="{}"'.format(string, add_string, add_value)
    print(result)
    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

You could give this a try, if you are open to using `urllib.urlencode` -

```
conditions = {"id": 83500, "type/name": "Printer", "name": "TEST API PRINTER"} 
query = {"pageSize": 1000, "conditions": conditions}
params = urllib.urlencode(query)
final_url = str(APIurl) + "&" + str(params)
response = requests.get(url=final_url)
```